# Render 3d models as isometric sprites

Tags: rendering

How can I render my 3d models as isometric sprites like the ones seen in Clash of clans?.

Please be detailed as possible because I am really confused.

Thank you!

Comment: So basically you want to make an isometric render?

Comment: If so, in the camera settings, change the lens type to Orthographic.

Comment: By "Sprites" do you mean 2D sprites?  i.e. no longer 3D objects?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65425/how-do-i-achieve-the-traditional-3-4-perspective-of-jrpgs-using-the-camera