# Render model in specific scale

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a model in real world scale and now I need render it in specific scale. Is there some way to set camera in specific distance from the model or any other way to get specific scale of render?

Comment: The scale of an object is only relative to any surrounding objects, so it's size when it's the only object in an image bears no reflection of it's scale. Is your image going to be real scale? Printed on what size poster and DPI? The object and camera [positions can be set](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/transforms.html) if you calculate the real world distance you want between the two.

Comment: Yes, image will be in real scale.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "scale" in renders, rendered output of Blender (or any other rendering software for that matter) is in raster graphics format, with pixels as only output unit.

You can adjust the DPI of said image in any external image editing software (like GIMP or Photoshop) but that is only used as reference and mostly for printing.

The perspective view also forbids any type scale relationship between the virtual scene and output format, since object size is always dependent on distance from camera. 
Only if you use an orthographic camera can there be any sense of direct correspondence of scene units and image output unmits.

Roughly speaking Blender uses the largest of the two output render dimensions as 1 unit for an orthographic camera. See [my answer here for more details](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64914/setting-camera-to-position-where-it-can-render-a-seamless-repetable-orthographic/64920#64920) about it