# Is there anyway to zoom the camera in orthographic view so that the object dimension corresponds to real world screen dimension?

Tags: 3d-view

I want to do some modelling for 3d printing and I would like to resize the object and compare it against a real physical object I have, hence the question.

Measuring the dimension first is of course another way, but I wonder whether we can do it in the way I suggested.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81164/render-model-in-specific-scale https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64920/19307