# Texture image size does not match the render size (internal render)

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

There is a jpg image 1000x1000 pixels.

In blender internal render.I set render resolution to 1000x1000.

Add a mesh plane, at position X-0 Y-0, with texture using the image, with texture coordinates set to Global

Camera is above the plane, at position X-0 Y-0. With orthographic view, with orthographic scale 1.

When i render the scene, i expect that the image texture on the plane
will match exactly the rendered image, since the image and render dimensions are same. But it does not match. Why?

Is there a way in blender to achieve this, so that a plane exactly matches the rendered dimensions, or maybe for a texture (in orthographic view of course).

p.s. this is not for setting a background image

Comment: How exactly does it not match, could you show us some screenshots? Textures are generally matched either to geometry or UV space, not render size. See related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64914/setting-camera-to-position-where-it-can-render-a-seamless-repetable-orthographic

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos but in this case the image is not set to match anything, it is just projected to the center of the global coordinate system (the texture coordinates is set to Global). And in my understanding  it should not be scaled, and should be exactly 1000x1000 pixels. But it is scaled a lot. It is an image of a persons face, and it renders like only one eye.

Comment: If you look through the camera with numpad-0 does view all of the image? To me it sounds like your sensor-size is to small

Comment: If you use a default plane, your plane will have size two, so either scale down your image plane, or set the ortographic size to something like 5

Comment: @Teck-freak does sensor-size matter in orthographic view? I set it to 1, it changed nothing. Also scale value of the plane  is 1, and plane's dimensions do not affect size of the texture image.

Comment: @EmcampInline is there any way you cam post a screenshot? The Scale-Value on a default-plane is 1, but its size is 2.

Comment: @Teck-freak If y resize the plane or even scale it, it does not affect the texture size. This is why i use projecting for mapping, so that the size of the image remained the same. I don't know what screenshot you want? Rendered image? Certain blender interface? Which panels to open in the screenshot?

Comment: @EmcampInline Wait a second. You use projecting for mapping? I haven't done this recently, but isn't there a option for scale in there too?

Comment: @EmcampInline can you post your blend somewhere?