# Render Blender's object with size defined in pixels

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, units

Let's say I have a 3D scene in Blender - I need to make an orthographic image where 1 Blender's unit will be exactly 1 pixel. Camera from above the scene, looking down (vector (0, 0, -1)).

Please don't offer post-processing scaling in the another 2D editor - that will break the quality and accuracy will not be good enough.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64914/setting-camera-to-position-where-it-can-render-a-seamless-repetable-orthographic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I get what you want, but this setup seems to get something like that: I put some colored cubes (each has one of three shadeless materials) on the diagonal of a a 10px x 10 px square.

[image]

The camera is ortho and its orthographic scale matches the output size. Antialiasing is obviously off.

This is the output (tiny 10px by 10px image):

[image]

setting resolution to 100x 100 and ortho scale to 100 you get this somewhat bigger image, but still each BU is a pixel:

[image]

Obviously you can change the aspect ratio, but keep the ortho scale equal to the bigger X/Y pixel value, like this:

[image]

Maybe this can work for you...

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted. The main idea is to set camera's scale identical to the biggest output image resolution's side in pixels