# How do I print to a particular scale?

Tags: scale

I'm trying to print some building plans. I would like for the plans on paper to be scaled so that 1 inch equals 1 foot. I have an orthographic camera set up but I don't know what to set the orthographic scale to so that I get the result that I want.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64914/setting-camera-to-position-where-it-can-render-a-seamless-repetable-orthographic/64920#64920