# How to scale Blender units into centimeters on Freestyle SVG export?

Tags: export, units, svg

I made a blueprint in Blender and I need to export it into SVG for a laser cut.
I tried units and centimeters.
I have 50 cm\units long plane.
When I use Freestyle SVG exporter, neither Adobe Illustrator nor Inkscape shows my plane to be 50 of anything (so I know the whole image scale is wrong). I tried to scale it in Inkscape and open that in Illustrator - the ruler still shows random lenght (DPI doesn't match?).
How do I manage this? Should I still use some measurement object and rescale in vector editors or is there some easier way?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64914/setting-camera-to-position-where-it-can-render-a-seamless-repetable-orthographic/64920#64920

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that doesn't explain much to me. 1 unit is 4000 px. And then? When I open SVG, Inkscape and Illustrator shows different lenghts in centimiters for the same object, and numbers are far away from mine.